# ZF2- Dynamically change application language on Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm using zend framework 2 and i'd like change the application language by clicking on a link for example.

this is my routing configuration :

```
'route'    => '/[:lang[/:controller[/:action[/:id]]]][[/page/:page]]',
```

and i'd defined en as default language :

```
'defaults' => array(
    'lang'     => 'en',
                   ),
```

on my module.php :

```
public function onBootstrap ($e) {

        $eventManager= $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();

        $routeCallback = function ($e) {
            $availableLanguages = array ('fr', 'en');
            $defaultLanguage = 'en';
            $language = "";
            $fromRoute = false;
            //see if language could be find in url
            if ($e->getRouteMatch()->getParam('lang')) {
                $language = $e->getRouteMatch()->getParam('lang');
                $fromRoute = true;

                //or use language from http accept
            } else {
                $headers = $e->getApplication()->getRequest()->getHeaders();
                if ($headers->has('Accept-Language')) {
                    $headerLocale = $headers->get('Accept-Language')->getPrioritized();
                    $language = substr($headerLocale[0]->getLanguage(), 0,2);
                }
            }
            if(!in_array($language, $availableLanguages) ) {
                $language = $defaultLanguage;
            }
            $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('translator')->setLocale($language);

        };

        $eventManager->attach(\Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent::EVENT_ROUTE, $routeCallback);
    }
```

Now this works perfectly, but i want to let the user change the language just by clicking on link for example.

Any suggestion??

Thanks for any help !

Comment: `tdutrion` in #zftalk channel IRC introduce: https://github.com/juriansluiman/SlmLocale for routing with web vistor from difference locations and languages.

Comment: this line save me, `$e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('translator')->setLocale($language);`  but using zf3 I just change to `$e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('MvcTranslator')->setLocale($language);` File: Module.php. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's to late but here the solution to your question :

> "Now this works perfectly, but i want to let the user change the
>   language just by clicking on link for example."

you can do a menu in your navigation like this (using bootstrap)

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="<?= $this->url($this->route, array('lang' => 'fr'));?>">
                                <span class="flag fr"></span> Français
                            </a></li>
                            <li><a href="<?=$this->url($this->route, array('lang' => 'en'));?>">
                                <span class="flag gb"></span> English
                            </a></li>
                        </ul>
```

Assure that your po/mo/and other traduction file are matching the pattern "fr\en" etc...

And it will be work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

from my experience it is a good practice to always store language in url. This way you will have a unique address for pages in different languages. Otherwise on the same url, different content will be shown for each language and you will not know what language is shown for bots, which is important if the application is a website. Using this approach it should not be difficult to provide multilanguage links for user.

Comment: Yes, that's what i did. i have a unique adsress the only thing which change on the address is the language parameter. As i said this works actually, Now what i need is to change the language at the demand of the user. so i need to change the dafault _en_ to have urls like this : `/fr/controller_name/action_name/..`

Comment: I would prefer to produce language url's by each controller for each action. Because, url's may differ for SEO purposes and some pages may not have contents in other languages, if this is the case, controller may produce default url (homepage of the language). 

otherwise with a preg_replace you can change the language part of the url.

Comment: Your opinion is best practice. But I don't press vote up button, because It isn't the solution for the question.